# Multiple debug and release configuration options in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, release, visual-studio-debugging

There are multiple alternatives for "release and debug" configuration in visual studio, I would like to know if they serve the same purpose.

1) Option 1: In the Visual Studio toolbar

[image: Visual Studio Menu]

2) Option 2: In the web.config file

[image: web.config]

3) Option 3: In the project properties window

[image]

4) Option 4: In the publish site configuration window

[image]

Is not one of these configuration options enough to deploy an application? Are all of them required? what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first one tells you in which one you are working right now (which configuration will be build if you say *build* - which one will start if you debug, etc.)
2. The second one handles what how the server will build your aspx/razor/etc. pages.
3. The third is there so that you can change the settings of the different configurations in the first place!
4. The last one tells which configuration you want to **deploy** - no matter what the current selected configuration (from 1) will show - of course it will depend on the settings in 3 and will most likely deploy the file from 2.

---

so no - it's not enough to have only one of those

Comment: So, base on what you say, I assume that "for deploying" I only should care about the configuration in the web.config file, because, at the end, how the server build the application is the important here for performance.?

Comment: no - AFAIK this only concerns the way your pages (in the Views folder) are compiled (remeber those are generated at runtime - it's more or less what ASP.NET does) - all other code is compiled on your machine and will end in the `bin` folder on the server  - if done correctly there should be almost no logic in those anyway - do just as the comment say: disable debug in the web.config on your server **and** deploy the release version - locally you usually want to work with the debug version (in your 1.))

Comment: btw: the folders will probably be named differently on asp.net webforms ... it's a long time since I needed to look at this abomination so I really don't remember ;)

Comment: Re: deploying: you generally want to use Release, which should use your more optimized build settings and the Web.Release.config transform, which will remove the debug attribute from web.config.